# Split string into multiple variables

Tags: string, stata

I have dataset that looks like this:

```
Var1
PASSED=50; NOT PASSED=10; GPA=1;
```

How can I produce the dataset below?

```
Pass     Not_pass      GPA  
  50           10        1
```

I used the following code but it did not work:

```
generate pass = subinstr(subinstr(word(Var1, 1), "PASSED=", "", .) if regexm(Var1, "PASSED=") == 1
replace pass = pass[_n+1] if pass[_n]=="" & pass[_n+1]!=""
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please see [how to format code blocks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).

Comment: I've edited your question according to your comment on another answer and according to the tag improvement from @lwileczek. But you should also add what you tried so far to apply the code to Stata, see also [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me:

```
clear
input strL Var1
"PASSED=50; NOT PASSED=10; GPA=1;"
end

split Var1, parse(";") generate(x)

forvalues i = 1 / 3 {
    generate v`i' = real(regexs(1)) if regexm(x`i',"([0-9]+)")
}

drop x*
rename (v1 v2 v3) (Pass Not_Pass GPA)

list 

     +----------------------------------------------------------+
     |                             Var1   Pass   Not_Pass   GPA |
     |----------------------------------------------------------|
  1. | PASSED=50; NOT PASSED=10; GPA=1;     50         10     1 |
     +----------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: If you found my answer helpful, please accept it with the check-mark and upvote it with the upper arrow.

Answer (score 0):

you can learn to split up strings in python using the [str](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html) documentation. For example

```
var1 = "PASSED=50; NOT PASSED=10; GPA=1;"
p, np, gpa, _ = var1.split(";")
```

This can actually leave some white space

```
print(np)
>>> ' NOT PASSED=10'
```

Which can be fixed with [strip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip)

```
print(np.strip())
>>> 'NOT PASSED=10'
```

Then you can set up a dictionary to store all of your data

```
d = {x.strip().split("=")[0]:x.split("=")[1] for x in [p, np, gpa]}
print(d)
>>> {'PASSED': '50', 'NOT PASSED': '10', 'GPA': '1'}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. Actually I wanted to do it in Stata. So can you please give me some suggestions how to do it in Stata?

Comment: Hello @NuraJannatMim, Stata was not tagged originally and, unfortunately, I do not have experience with it.  I'll update the tags on your question.

Answer (score 0):

Using `moss` from SSC is another way to do it in Stata.

```
clear
input strL Var1
"PASSED=50; NOT PASSED=10; GPA=1;"
end

ssc install moss 
moss Var1, match("([0-9]+)") regex 

rename (_match?) (Pass Not_Pass GPA)
drop _* 

list 

     +----------------------------------------------------------+
     |                             Var1   Pass   Not_Pass   GPA |
     |----------------------------------------------------------|
  1. | PASSED=50; NOT PASSED=10; GPA=1;     50         10     1 |
     +----------------------------------------------------------+
```